# How to stringify method lines?

Tags: ruby

Can Ruby take a method like this:

```
def a_few_methods
  method1
  method2
end
```

...and create an array like this?

```
['method1', 'method2']
```

I'm doing the following, which works, but it seems clunky:

```
class Foo

  def self.method_array
    %w[method1 method2]
  end

  def a_few_methods
    self.class.method_array.each { |s| send s }
  end
end
```

I see that Method inherits Object, but I don't see any way to get 'under the hood' and grab things from it, aside from reading the source file into a string. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
def self.method_array
    arr = [method(:method1), method(:method2)
end
```

And then I would call it like

```
self.class.method_array.each { |s| s.call }
```

I created a program that looks like this:

```
def test_one
    puts "test one"
end

def test_two
    puts "test two"
end


def few_methods
    arr = [method(:test_one), method(:test_two)]
end


a = few_methods
a.each {|i| i.call  }
```

And when I run it I get the text printed out line by line. 
Don't know if this is something that might help you.

Comment: Why do you create a local variable and then completely ignore it?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag Which local variable? You mean `arr`?  Because it's being returned by default in Ruby. It doesn't require explicit return keyword in methods like some other languages. Another great thing with Ruby is that you can extend any class you like. If you wanted to add this to a String class you'd write class Foo < String and all String objects could use the methods of this class

Comment: But you never use `arr`. You could just get rid of it and your code would work the exact same way, and it wouldn't confuse future readers of your code. Oh, and no, if you inherit from `String`, then no strings would be able to use the methods of `Foo`, only `Foo` objects would be able to.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I just realise what I wrote. I was going to write if Foo was declared as a String class, then it would be part of the String. It's still early in the morning here @Jörg W Mittag , and I didn't have my cup of coffee . Yes, you're right. I could have gotten rid of the variable, but I thought it'd be easier for someone to see it this way,  since I didn't understand it in the very beginning with all Ruby magical stuff.